# Dots between navbar li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add three dots between the bootstrap 4 navbar

elements. In order to do this I tried the li:before statement but the dots appear only in the upper right corner instead of between the li elements. What I am doing wrong here - it makes me crazy ;-)

My CSS is like this:

```
body {
  min-height: 75rem;
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
}

li:before {
  content: '•••';
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 0px;
  color: aqua;
}
```

And the HTML is just from the simple bootstrap example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Fixed top navbar example for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="navbar-top-fixed.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" 
        aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a font icon?

Comment: You need `position: relative;` on the `li`, or else the pseudo will relate to the next non-static positioned element, and if none, to the viewport.

Comment: @LGSon: This worked great - I just missed the relative part on the position! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), and particularly this bit:

> **absolute**
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.
>
> ***It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor**, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block.*
>
> Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

You want your `li:before` to be absolutely positioned relative to it's parent `li`. Therefore you should give your `li` a `position: relative`.

```css
body {
  min-height: 75rem;
  padding-top: 4.5rem;
}


li {
position: relative;}

li:before {
  content: '•••';
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 0px;
  color: aqua;
}

/* only for debugging */
#navbarCollapse {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" 
            aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </body>
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any more help with this.